# Eclipse Cache Corruption cause error with ADT gen file

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have an android project and frequently generate a wrong `R.java` file driving me mad to fix problems.

Now, I have a project with custom icon buttons for example

```
bt_icon1.png
bt_icon2.png
```

etc.

I have deleted `bt_icon1.png` to use another resource with the same name

Result?

```
Unparsed AAPT Error, resource already defined.
```

The resource has been removed, I have tried to clean project an rebuilt, 
but I get always the same error because in the autogen file `R.java` there is a line
`public static final int bt_icon1=0x7f02000d;` that refers to  the removed icon...

I have tried to manually remove the line but is recreated every time...

I have tried to remove the entire `R.java` but Eclipse generate always a wrong version of the file.

There is a solution that don't force me to remove `.metadata` folder in the workspace and re-import all the projects every time???

My ADT is the latest version,my Eclipse is updated to latest release, and I have the latest SDK.